# I keep getting this error "mongoose.model is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am getting this error but I can't seem to find the problem, I have tried the following things:

1. reinstalling mongoose
2. changing `export default` to `module.exports`
3. changing MONGO_URI from "mongodb://localhost:27017/" to "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/"
4. tried to import mongoose in Product.js using "import" instead of required
5. tried removing "mongoose.model = {}"
6. tried importing connectDb before product in getproduct.js

but the issue is still not fixed I am still getting the following error:

```
error - models\Product.js (23:24) @ model
error - TypeError: mongoose.model is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./models/Product.js:48:75)
    at (api)/./models/Product.js (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\pages\api\getproducts.js:42:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/getproducts.js:5:73)
    at (api)/./src/pages/api/getproducts.js (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\pages\api\getproducts.js:52:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\pages\api\getproducts.js:62:39)
    at C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\pages\api\getproducts.js:63:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\.next\server\pages\api\getproducts.js:66:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:506:34)
    at DevServer.handleApiRequest (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:861:21)
    at Object.fn (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:815:46)
    at async Router.execute (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:243:32)
    at async DevServer.runImpl (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:432:29)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:814:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:375:20)
    at async C:\Users\CoreCom\Desktop\next js\havenwear\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:157:99
  21 |   // module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
  22 |
> 23 | export default mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

here is the code:

**Product.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required:true},
    slug: {type: String, required:true , unique:true},
    desc: {type: String, required:true},
    img: {type: String, required:true},
    category: {type: String, required:true},
    size: {type: String},
    color: {type: String},
    price: {type: Number, required:true},
    availableQty: {type: Number, required:true},
    
    
  }, {timestamps:true} );
  mongoose.model = {}

  // mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema)
  // module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);

export default mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

**mongoose.js:**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const connectDb = handler => async (req, res) => {
    // checking if connection is already extablished
    if(mongoose.connections[0].readyState){
        return handler(req,res)
    }
    
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    return handler(req,res);
}
export default connectDb
```

**getproducts.js:**

```
import Product from "../../../models/Product"
import connectDb from "../../../middleware/mongoose"
const handler = async (req,res)=>{
    let products = await Product.find()
    res.status(200).json({products})
  }

export default connectDb(handler)
```

**.env.local:**

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/codeswears
```

Comment: `mongoose.model = {}`... err, what? I know you said you _"tried removing"_ that but why is it there at all? And why is it in the code in your question if you removed it?

Comment: Don't mix module styles. If your using ES6 modules (`import` / `export`), use them everywhere

Comment: I am actually following a tutorial where the instructor used it and It was working fine, what I mean I tried removing is I also tried to run the code without it but it still didn't work @Phil